# Как следать сайт "несужаемее" определенного числа пикселей?

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, html, вёрстка

У меня есть сайт. И когда я сужаю окно браузера более чем до 800 пикселей, скажем, начинает вториться безобразие.
Как сделать так, чтобы он перестал сужаться в этой точке? Пробовал добавить невидимый ДИВ шириной 800 пикселей, не помогло. Какие еще идеи, товарищи? Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
min-width: 800px;
```

Comment: о, спасибо!
только поправлю, min-width

Comment: да Вы правы с ошибкой написал